# Best way to extract data from dict with multiple dicts and lists?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a novice who seems to have a very hard time when it comes to dicts especially when they seemed to be nested with another dict with a list of dicts.

I think that's what I am dealing with here.

```
>>> print data
{u'service_group_stat': 
{u'status': 3, u'protocol': 2, u'name': u'SG_ACCOUNT.BUSINESS.COM_443', u'cur_reqs': 0, u'resp_pkts': 4349047684, u'cur_conns': 71, u'total_reqs': 0, u'total_reqs_succ': 0, u'req_pkts': 1808605274, u'req_bytes': 285168980113, 
u'member_stat_list': 
[{u'status': 1, u'resp_bytes': 10134966691, u'cur_reqs': 0, u'resp_pkts': 7834233, u'cur_conns': 11, u'total_reqs': 0, u'server': u'WWW0006', u'req_pkts': 3134918, u'req_bytes': 447460215, u'total_reqs_succ': 0, u'tot_conns': 52311, u'port': 81}, 
{u'status': 1, u'resp_bytes': 12396718148, u'cur_reqs': 0, u'resp_pkts': 9572363, u'cur_conns': 5, u'total_reqs': 0, u'server': u'WWW0005', u'req_pkts': 3870142, u'req_bytes': 548725475, u'total_reqs_succ': 0, u'tot_conns': 61464, u'port': 81}, 
{u'status': 1, u'resp_bytes': 15868605964, u'cur_reqs': 0, u'resp_pkts': 12282023, u'cur_conns': 15, u'total_reqs': 0, u'server': u'WWW0004', u'req_pkts': 5051483, u'req_bytes': 711362272, u'total_reqs_succ': 0, u'tot_conns': 80898, u'port': 81}, 
{u'status': 1, u'resp_bytes': 1832290858664, u'cur_reqs': 0, u'resp_pkts': 1417192127, u'cur_conns': 23, u'total_reqs': 0, u'server': u'WWW0003', u'req_pkts': 575717964, u'req_bytes': 92624447982, u'total_reqs_succ': 0, u'tot_conns': 7265009, u'port': 81}, 
{u'status': 1, u'resp_bytes': 1909851841929, u'cur_reqs': 0, u'resp_pkts': 1479318756, u'cur_conns': 14, u'total_reqs': 0, u'server': u'WWW0002', u'req_pkts': 634692796, u'req_bytes': 97240370978, u'total_reqs_succ': 0, u'tot_conns': 7130096, u'port': 81}, 
{u'status': 1, u'resp_bytes': 1839297678302, u'cur_reqs': 0, u'resp_pkts': 1422848182, u'cur_conns': 3, u'total_reqs': 0, u'server': u'WWW0001', u'req_pkts': 586137971, u'req_bytes': 93596613191, u'total_reqs_succ': 0, u'tot_conns': 7172117, u'port': 81}], 
u'resp_bytes': 5619840669698, u'tot_conns': 21761895}}
```

It seems to me that "data" is a dict that contains another dict which contains a list of multiple dicts ?

I seem to be able to do the basics and extract the first level of data related to "service_group_stat" and then associate variables such as:

```
>>> sgname = data['service_group_stat']['name']
>>> sgconnects = data['service_group_stat']['cur_conns']
>>> print sgname
SG_ACCOUNT.BUSINESS.COM_443
>>> print sgconnects
71
```

I'm failing at figuring out how to go deeper with this.

How to get to the server level and associate the data to the individual servers.

Ultimately being able to present both the group data as well as server data such as:

```
Service Group:      SG_ACCOUNT.BUSINESS.COM_443     Total SG Connections:   71
Server:             WWW0001                         Server Connections:     3
Server:             WWW0002                         Server Connections:     14
Server:             WWW0003                         Server Connections:     23
Server:             WWW0004                         Server Connections:     15
Server:             WWW0005                         Server Connections:     5
Server:             WWW0006                         Server Connections:     11
```

Any advice on how best to group and associate the data to variables that I can then use to display or print how I deem fit?

Comment: What exactly are you asking - how to access the data in the dict, and in the dicts and lists inside the dict?

Comment: Yes, guess I didn't do a good job at explaining.  That is exactly what I am trying to do.  Its access the data within the second level of dicts and lists.

Comment: humm.. so I just noticed something I didn't try.  sgservers = data['service_group_stat']['member_stat_list']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is `data` pretty-printed using `pprint`:

```
{'service_group_stat': {'cur_conns': 71,
                    'cur_reqs': 0,
                    'member_stat_list': [{'cur_conns': 11,
                                          'cur_reqs': 0,
                                          'port': 81,
                                          'req_bytes': 447460215,
                                          'req_pkts': 3134918,
                                          'resp_bytes': 10134966691,
                                          'resp_pkts': 7834233,
                                          'server': 'WWW0006',
                                          'status': 1,
                                          'tot_conns': 52311,
                                          'total_reqs': 0,
                                          'total_reqs_succ': 0},
                                         {'cur_conns': 5,
                                          'cur_reqs': 0,
                                          'port': 81,
                                          'req_bytes': 548725475,
                                          'req_pkts': 3870142,
                                          'resp_bytes': 12396718148,
                                          'resp_pkts': 9572363,
                                          'server': 'WWW0005',
                                          'status': 1,
                                          'tot_conns': 61464,
                                          'total_reqs': 0,
                                          'total_reqs_succ': 0},
                                         {'cur_conns': 15,
                                          'cur_reqs': 0,
                                          'port': 81,
                                          'req_bytes': 711362272,
                                          'req_pkts': 5051483,
                                          'resp_bytes': 15868605964,
                                          'resp_pkts': 12282023,
                                          'server': 'WWW0004',
                                          'status': 1,
                                          'tot_conns': 80898,
                                          'total_reqs': 0,
                                          'total_reqs_succ': 0},
                                         {'cur_conns': 23,
                                          'cur_reqs': 0,
                                          'port': 81,
                                          'req_bytes': 92624447982,
                                          'req_pkts': 575717964,
                                          'resp_bytes': 1832290858664,
                                          'resp_pkts': 1417192127,
                                          'server': 'WWW0003',
                                          'status': 1,
                                          'tot_conns': 7265009,
                                          'total_reqs': 0,
                                          'total_reqs_succ': 0},
                                         {'cur_conns': 14,
                                          'cur_reqs': 0,
                                          'port': 81,
                                          'req_bytes': 97240370978,
                                          'req_pkts': 634692796,
                                          'resp_bytes': 1909851841929,
                                          'resp_pkts': 1479318756,
                                          'server': 'WWW0002',
                                          'status': 1,
                                          'tot_conns': 7130096,
                                          'total_reqs': 0,
                                          'total_reqs_succ': 0},
                                         {'cur_conns': 3,
                                          'cur_reqs': 0,
                                          'port': 81,
                                          'req_bytes': 93596613191,
                                          'req_pkts': 586137971,
                                          'resp_bytes': 1839297678302,
                                          'resp_pkts': 1422848182,
                                          'server': 'WWW0001',
                                          'status': 1,
                                          'tot_conns': 7172117,
                                          'total_reqs': 0,
                                          'total_reqs_succ': 0}],
                    'name': 'SG_ACCOUNT.BUSINESS.COM_443',
                    'protocol': 2,
                    'req_bytes': 285168980113,
                    'req_pkts': 1808605274,
                    'resp_bytes': 5619840669698,
                    'resp_pkts': 4349047684,
                    'status': 3,
                    'tot_conns': 21761895,
                    'total_reqs': 0,
                    'total_reqs_succ': 0}}
```

Using this info, we can now process it.
For each server in `member_stat_list`, we can print the data in the format you said like this:

```
for server in data["service_group_stat"][["member_stat_list"]:
    print("Server:".ljust(20," ")+server["server"].ljust(32," ")+"Server Connections:".ljust(24," ")+str(server["cur_conns"]))
```

Comment: Ah that's great!  I was just trying to figure out the best way to do what you did with the "for server in data["service_group_stat"][["member_stat_list"]:"

Answer (score 2):

To access data further inside your data structure, you can just keep using the brackets after. So, for example, let's say you wanted to access the status of the first 'member'. You could do:

```
value = data['service_group_stat']['member_stat_list'][0]['status']
```

What this does - it access the value associated with the key service_group_stat, which happens to be a dict. Then, it accesses the value in the nested dict, which happens to be a list. To grab from a list, you use the index (number). Basically, you can just stack the brackets further and further depending on how deep your data structure is.

Comment: Thank you!  Let me go play around with that.